# Correct way to manage memory in Qt when exposing QObject class into qml?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm using C++ to code the most of my program logic. I like exposing C++ classes into QML so that the QML can use JS to do many complex jobs. However, here comes a problem:

If the C++ function return a `QObject*`

```
Q_INVOKABLE QObject* parseJson(const QString& someArguments)
{
    return new SomeClassExtendsQObject(someArguments);
}
```

which is then assigned to a `JS` variable and used

```
var result = exposingCppObj.parseJson("I'm Arguments");
result.someMemberFunction(...);
.....
```

if I use

```
delete result
```

in QML JS, is the instance really freed like it would be in C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An object created in C++ but accessible from QML can have two [ownership states](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#ObjectOwnership-enum):
`QQmlEngine::CppOwnership` and `QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership`.  You rarely need to set this state as Qt can usually work out the appropriate one. In your example since the object is created from a QML call, it is automatically assigned `QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership`.

When an object is assigned `QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership` the JS garbage collector will destroy it when necessary; there's rarely need to explicitly destroy it.

One last thing, if you do want to destroy an object in QML, use [`destroy()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html#deleting-objects-dynamically).  The JS [`delete`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp) keyword is for removing both the value of a property and a property itself from objects.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer!